# App Engine's UnindexedProperty contains strange code

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Please help me understand this:

On v1.6.6 it's in line 2744 of `google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py`:

```
class UnindexedProperty(Property):
  """A property that isn't indexed by either built-in or composite indices.

  TextProperty and BlobProperty derive from this class.
  """
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
    """Construct property. See the Property class for details.

    Raises:
      ConfigurationError if indexed=True.
    """
    self._require_parameter(kwds, 'indexed', False)



    kwds['indexed'] = True
    super(UnindexedProperty, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
 .
 .
 .
```

After they constrained the indexed parameter to be False - They set it to True!

Comment: @kamens thanks for the bounty.

+500, This question probably really bothered you :)

Comment: I can't take credit, @alpert offered the bounty...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before 1.2.2, you could do filter queries for any property type, even Text and Blob. They did only return empty lists, but it worked. Version 1.2.2 introduced the `indexed` attribute for properties which allows you to disable indexing of selected properties[1]. Since then, the property you want to query on must be indexed or it will throw an exception.

We know that Text and Blob properties can not be indexed. Not changing anything else, queries on those properties would be raising exceptions from 1.2.2 on (which they didn't before). In order to not introduce a regression and break existing apps, the line `kwds['indexed'] = True` was added to the `UnindexedProperty` class.

If we would have control over all the depending code, it would have been a cleaner solution to start raising an exception. But in the light of not breaking existing apps, it was decided to patch it.

You can try it yourself by changing `kwds['indexed'] = True` to `kwds['indexed'] = False` and run this snippet:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class TestModel(db.Model):
  text = db.TextProperty()

TestModel(text='foo').put()
print TestModel.all().filter('text =', 'foo').fetch(10)
```

[1] http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/RELEASE_NOTES#1165

Comment: So UnindexedProperty simply enforces that the code doesn't set `indexed=True` but would build an index on a (non-Text/Blob) property?

Comment: (An example matching @alpert's description would be the ArrayProperty in aetycoon: https://github.com/Arachnid/aetycoon/blob/master/__init__.py)

Comment: @BenAlpert, yes but it shouldn't. I filed a bug to get this cleared up. Thanks for starting this code archaeology session. FWIW, the actual check is done here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/datastore.py#1031